# Cannot use setData()

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-extensions

For the life of me, I am unable to figure out how to use setData() for a Marker.

My code:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(title).snippet(snippet);

Marker marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

marker.setData(data); // This doens't work, simply says cannot resolve.
```

I have the following in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
```

How the heck do I use setData?!

Comment: see : https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

Comment: related post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816471/importing-androidmapsextensions-into-android-studio

Comment: @Hacketo the problem being is that the documentation is terrible.

Comment: is your `map` type `com.androidmapsextensions.GoogleMap` ?

Comment: Seems it wasn't, but when I changed it, I got errors with my line of code "map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();"

Answer (score 0):

From Android Maps Extensions migration "guide":

> When migrating to Extensions, all you have to change is:
>
> - a couple of import statements,
> - `SupportMapFragment` (or `MapView`) full class names in xml and
> - call `getExtendedMap` instead of `getMap` on `SupportMapFragment` (or `MapView`).