# Android download google support libraries

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using AIDE to programming in my android phone
And i must download any support library to use it in my project libs folder
So i want to tell me how to download google support libraries
Like firebase.google.jar
And google gms library and other libraries
Is there a link? 
Help me how to download it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading and including JAR files (deprecated) you should be using the gradle build system and including it in the dependencies.  There is a step-by-step [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) explaining how to use it.

/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Thank u.  but this doesnt work with me because i am using mobile app to programming and its name AIDE.. So when i do this step it doesnt work.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you use Android Studio.  It is the only IDE that Google officially supports and most professionals use it as well.
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: According to this link AIDE does support maven.  Maybe this answer will help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007146/how-to-use-libraries-in-aide?rq=1