# Hiw do I add Maven libs to .Aide IDE

Tags: java, maven, aide-ide

I followed a post about adding Maven Libs to .Aide. I can't get them all to work. Any ideas? I'm trying to agreed the javax and java.awt libs

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26032696/3992939) help ?

Comment: Those were the directions I tried to follow. I actually got confused on which to download. .Aide, though I have settings pointing to my  existing Maven files, has started to act up. I have even uninstalled then reinstalled to no avail. But I'm hoping if I get this lib problem fixed things will go back to normal. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can add the jar libs at following Folder:

> PROJECT/app/libs/LIB_GOES_HERE.JAR